# Seeing Google spreadsheet ID without sharing it to mail address

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am confused about using Google spreadsheet API. and here is the thing: A website creating a spreadsheet in my Google Drive everyday. So I want to get that created spreadsheet by automatically. And to achieve that I followed these steps:

in **Google Console:**

- enabled the Drive
- created a credentials.

then wrote the following code below.

```
def auth(self):
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    secretKey = "client_secrets.json"

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(secretKey, scopes=scopes)
    service = discovery.build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)

    client_address = 'mycredentialEmail@here.com'
    drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    services = {
        "sheet_service": service,
        "drive_service": drive
    }

    return services

def sheetId(self):
    services = self.auth()

    # get the spreadsheets folder 
    folder_id = ".......1rn00ox"
    fileList = services["drive_service"].files().list(fields="files(id, createdTime)").execute()
    print(fileList)

    today = datetime.date.today()
    spreadsheetId = [e['id'] for e in fileList.get('files', []) if dateutil.parser.parse(e.get('createdTime')).date() == today]

    return spreadsheetId[0]
```

Okay, it's working but there is a **one problem** here. I can't see the spreadsheet ID unless I `share` it with my credentials email address... So everyday I need to go into the newly created spreadsheet and share it my `credentials` email, but it's not very automatic? Is there any better way? For example, how can I share the **client_adress** in the code, not on the website by manually, and see the spreadsheet?

thank you.

Comment: What is `client_address for the access`?

Comment: I am using service account, and service account mail for the access @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. `q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'"` returns only Spreadsheet files. This is the specification. So, about your situation that the empty result is returned with `q` and one Google Spreadsheet is returned without `q`, I cannot understand. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution. So now I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: no need to apologize actually. I figure it all a lot but the thing I couldn't understand is, When I check the name of the spreadsheet in `fileList`  it's 
 **Getting Started** but I don't have a spreadsheet with that name? So I tried with a new query and pass the folder name... `q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and parents in '"+folder_id+"' and trashed = false",` but no luck it's returns empty... though it's not empty... https://imgur.com/a/kyphyhm

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the reason your issue cannot be resolved is due to my poor skill. So I have to apologize for this. From your image in replying, in this case, are those Google Spreadsheet and folders shared with the email of service account? If it's not, the files cannot be retrieved with the service account. Because the service account is different from the users Google account. How about this?

Comment: yes, you were right about that. If I manually enter the spreadsheet and add the client_address to shared. then I can see the spread sheet ID. BUT this is the problem... do I need to add the client_address manually everytime? hmm thats a bit awkward :) @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I had already proposed the method for achieving your replying in my answer.

Comment: What if your script creates the permission when it creates the file? http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/drive_v3.permissions.html#create

Comment: is email id's are different drive account , email which creates spreadsheet in drive and email which access spread sheet?

Comment: @Tay, add the script which creates the spreadsheet

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram yes it's different,  email is client_secret's credentials address I created in the google console... the problem is I am not sure how can I do that... could you give and example based on the code that I provided above.